# Let's talk about answers and their quality

Tags: discussion, answers

A long time ago the WB.SE community was discussing [whether to adhere to the Back It Up! policy or not](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/back-it-up-policies). Those discussions are not very relevant today since most participants are long gone now. And the current generation of users has very different standards compared to the early days of the WB.SE. I think that it is time to talk about answers and their quality again.

[The WB.SE tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) says: '*With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about worldbuilding.*'

I believe it is an admirable goal. But it does not say whether this library should contain answers with good, reliable information or it can be made of speculations and wild guesses. The [Help Centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is also not very specific:

> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

As it is now there is no formal rule addressing the quality of the answers. There are also no guidelines for answers, except for those stated in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), but it is a rule that is systematically ignored on the current WB.SE (some high reputation and active on Meta users do not even know about its existence).

Today's WB.SE has a great number of answers that appear to me as poorly researched, based on speculations, unverified assumptions, personal preferences, 'common sense', ideologies, tropes, and so on<sup>**1**</sup>. As a result, it is not possible for me to trust the answers (not to mention that [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/) is a much better source for tropes). Their best use is to test the audience, their preferences, values, and beliefs.

Speculative answers and wild guesses are not bad per se. And they can be immensely helpful. Even answers based on wrong assumptions can be helpful if those assumptions are clearly stated. The problem is that they do not work well with the existing requirements for questions. The WB.SE does not welcome speculative questions and requires prior research. There is also a rule against opinion-based questions, but at this point of the WB.SE history, it is not clear what constitutes opinion-based.

I do not have a clear position on this. I would like the expectations for answers and questions to match each other (researched questions and researched answers, for example) because I believe in [reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(social_psychology)) and it seems to me that it would be easier to keep the quality of the questions high if the answers are of equally high quality. However, I do not expect the community to support this view or the WB.SE to uphold it. At this time I am trying to learn what other people think about the answers and whether there should be some guidelines for them.

---

**Clarification**:

The purpose of this query is not to start a debate about my own position regarding the quality of answers or my evaluation of answers. The former is not possible as ***I do not have a clear position*** (which I stated before) and ***I am not proposing any policies or guidelines***. The latter is something that I wanted to avoid because the discussion will turn to be about specific answers and their merits rather than the general quality of answers and whether any guidelines are needed.

My intent was expressed in the last sentence of the original version: **At this time I am trying to learn what other people think about the answers and whether there should be some guidelines for them.** In other words, I wanted people to share their thoughts about answers and their quality and whether any guidelines are necessary.

---

Since @elemtilas insists on providing specific examples of what I would consider a low-quality answer and explicitly states that they would want to hear my opinion about their own answer, I will use their answer to this query (as of 4 February 2022, 18:20 GMT) as such an example.

There are 2 big problems with this answer:

1. it is a response to the linked Back It Up! policy discussion, not this query (and @elemtilas does acknowledge this)

   It is worth noting that @elemtilas justifies this approach by saying that my query is unfinished and not clear enough to them. They even threatened to VTC it.

   It should be mentioned that @elemtilas is the author of [Is it Fair to Encourage People to NOT Answer Questions that Need to be Closed?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/is-it-fair-to-encourage-people-to-not-answer-questions-that-need-to-be-closed), where they advocate for not answering questions that they find to be unsatisfactory. Therefore, their own response is not only inconsistent with the [WB.SE guidelines for answers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) but also with their own position regarding answering questions.
2. in their response @elemtilas does not represent the original Back It Up! policy or discussion about it accurately (and they agree with this evaluation)

   The way @elemtilas builds their argument and formats their post distorts the original meaning of the Back It Up! policy and may lead readers to believe that it was an attempt to require references for every single answer. It was never the case. [The core of the policy was](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/78/78906): ***Every answer needs to justify the conclusions it comes to.***

I see this kind of answer not only as poor-quality but detrimental to the WB.SE. It sets a precedent for being off-topic. It also misleads the readers. In addition, it makes it impossible for me to trust the author's words even when it comes to their expressed attitudes and positions on issues because their acts are not consistent with their words.

I will not provide any additional specific examples of low-quality answers as I do not believe that it would be very constructive to this discussion. However, since @elemtilas has difficulty understanding my point about disaster myths I will add a note on this.

Every answer that features mass panic or social chaos as inevitable and 'natural' (as in 'it's human nature') outcomes in disaster scenarios is an answer that lacks research because both of these notions are among debunked disaster myths. There is even [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_response_to_disasters) about this. Moreover, these answers are, if I put it kindly, irresponsible since the propagation of disaster myths worsens the outcomes for real people affected by real disasters.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> <sup>My personal favourites are mass-panic and social chaos. These myths were debunked so many times (please google for 'disaster myths'), yet, almost every question related to disastrous scenarios will have answers suggesting that mass-panic, looting, rioting, and social collapse are inevitable.</sup>

<sup>This lack of research is not limited to social phenomena, it shows in answers to questions that are related to natural sciences as well.</sup>

Comment: isn't worldbuilding.stackexchange a site where the asker is supposed to explain what is a good answer?

Comment: SE [produced a flow chart about answering questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/22/are-some-questions-too-simple/). It's a bit outdated, but certainly applicable. The chart has been around for ten years with dubious results. One of the bigger problems is expecting new users to dig through the mountain of history to discover expectations - another problem is keeping that mountain of gems up-to-date.

Comment: @PythonProgrammersaresouless Not exactly. The WB.SE rules require defining the scope of the answer by constraining the question. There are also 2 tags (science-based and hard-science) that require existing science with or without citations. These tags are often ignored by the answerers, though. My query is not about questioners, though. It is about expectations for the answerers, their ethics, and their attitude. It is very easy to push all responsibility to the questioners. But at the end of the day, there is nothing that they can do about answerers who provide poor answers.

Comment: I'd actually love to see some links to examples of responses that you think are poorly researched, based on speculation, unverified assumptions, personal preferences, 'common sense', ideologies, tropes, and so forth. (Especially mine!) I do have some thoughts on the quality of responses, and also some thoughts on the linked Meta discussion; but without a few really good examples, I'm not quite sure how to approach your actual question.

Comment: @elemtilas I do not want this discussion to devolve into a discussion of specific answers and their merits. I am not interested in opinions about specific answers, I am looking to see the general attitude. I also have some very strong feelings about some poor quality answers and it would be hard for me to contain those feelings. In addition to this, there is really no need to embarrass people.

Comment: Friend, I'm not asking you to rip into the merits of actual answers. I'm asking you to ***Back It Up!*** by giving some examples of what you mean by answers that are *poorly researched, based on speculations, unverified assumptions, personal preferences, 'common sense', ideologies, tropes*. If you can't or don't want to do that, then I really see no further reason to continue. I'll downvote your question for being **unclear, unuseful and demonstrating no effort**; and then VTC because you're just teasing everyone with a question that you won't clarify.

Comment: @elemtilas I brought the example of disaster myths, specifically mass panic and social collapse that are featured uncritically in many answers to the questions about disasters and post-apocalyptic scenarios. Please also note that my query ends with this: At this time I am trying to learn what other people think about the answers and whether there should be some guidelines for them. In other words, I am interested in learning your thoughts on the subject of answers, not debating my own position. If you absolutely need a specific example, your answer here would do just fine.

Comment: Okay. You didn't actually "give an example" -- you only mentioned a category without any kind of context. Serious question: If you want to learn what we think of answers, how do you expect us to respond if we have no example answers to evaluate? You want me to evaluate my own answer? Fine! It's incomplete at present because the querent **REFUSES to clarify his query**.

Comment: Sorry: I had to downvote your query because you've refused to clarify. This is Meta: you really do need to get to the point, especially since you have a solid concern! I can't help you if you don't help yourself first.

Comment: @elemtilas I do not ask you to evaluate any answers. I would be more interested in your criteria for evaluation. I also think that you misrepresent my actions. I do not refuse to clarify. I am attempting to do so. Could it be that you refuse to understand my intent? I also wonder why is it not possible for you to bring your own examples if you need them so much? There are precedents of you evaluating answers before.

Comment: SE *"Every answer needs to justify the conclusions it comes to."* still holds: mermaids use ballet shoes for walking on land, **because** their ankle muscle still sits in the right place. The because-phrase should be enough justification. When it is plausible, that is when a *reader of the story* finds it plausible. Children's stories have very implausible characters and environments. Readers of fantasy may accept bizarre scenarios, like turtle people living in a swamp. Readers of science fiction however may be regarded as savants, you don't want to loose their interest. Back-it-up is needed.

Comment: @Goodies I tend to see justifications in the context of intra-world consistency. We do not know who is the intended audience for the world and we do not require to provide this information. But we can build our answers in such a way that they do not break the world (given that the questioner provides sufficient information).

Comment: *"We do not know who is the intended audience for the world"* @Otkin that is why I advocate to look at tags and actively maintain tags. When I find a topic without science or reality tag, I tend to set my expectations a bit lower.. we rarely have opportunity, to make sure our answers are consistent with the rest of the opener's world. The SE rules demand one question at a time, in many questions there is little context provided. Creature design is primarily about the creature, less about the world around it. This is often not handy or good (agree !) but as said many times.. openers don't edit.

Comment: @Goodies I think that proper use of tags is a great thing. But I am not sure that editing tags without the OP's input is a good idea. The OP should not lose control over their question. In addition to this, tags serve only as a suggestion, they cannot force answerers to give proper answers. Take a look at Q with the hard-science tag. How many answers without any references (or partial references) do they get? I think it might be a good idea to encourage answerers to produce high-quality answers (in addition to whatever is being done to improve questions).

Answer (score 4):

**Our Stack is not and should not be Physics.SE-lite**

- How do you cite or document an answer about a user's magic system? Or the magical creature they're designing? Or the magical weapon they're designing? This is the fundamental problem with the "Opinion Based" closure reason — it's not possible to become an expert in Magic from the perspective originally intended by Stack Exchange. This is especially a problem when a querent, who ostensibly knows their own magic system better than anyone else, gets an answer from someone who is familiar with a dozen magic systems used in various RPG games and/or novels. Which one is the "expert?"
- How much documentation or citation is deemed satisfactory when answering questions about dystopian governments? post-zombie-apocalypse societies? or time travel? All of these can draw from (and would be benefited by) current mathematics or historical conditions that reasonably represent the goal of the OP. But so would drawing on years of reading time-travel, post-apocalypse, and dystopian-government novels as what other authors have done is a perspective as valid as any science-based or history-based answer. But should we ignore the perspective of a user who grew up, for example, in East L.A. and has a unique perspective of what "post apocalypse" might mean, despite a complete lack of credentials?

And that's the problem. In my opinion, *we already focus way, way, way too much on being a science-only Q&A site.* We're robbing the site of the one thing that really makes it valuable: imagination.

- For my last example, how do you document the behavioral responses of an artificial intelligence? or a government? or a military contingent based on a provided context or circumstance? How do you design the sexuality of an alien species that is unrelated to Humanity or any terrestrial creature? Questions like these that are not well bounded are quickly closed, but we've answered those that are well bounded and don't reflect the Help Center restriction that we don't answer questions about character choices. You, yourself, have noted in [a previous Meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8312/40609) that questions like these should either be left to the <s>experts</s> *to people who take the time to research the issues such that an expert in the field would not be disappointed by the result* or excluded entirely rather than risk "falsehoods."<sup>1</sup> If we held all questions to that standard, the only people answering would be accredited experts in their fields (yeah... magic...) or no questions would ever be allowed on the site.

**How do we improve answers knowing that all kinds of people will use this site?**

*I once had a comment-discussion with an advanced user over at English.SE. He was constantly trying to push questions from English-as-a-second-language users and your-question-is-too-basic users off the site. When I pointed out to him that there wasn't actually a practical way to do that without violating SE's CoC, his response was, "can't we professionals have a site for ourselves?" The answer, since SE doesn't require CVs as part of the account creation process, is "no."*

Stack Exchange must be for more than "professionals" — experts in their fields who not only have been educated well enough to provide authoritative answers but who also have the time to sit down and write thorough, documented answers. I'm only guessing, but I suspect a substantial portion of our users haven't finished (and may not finish) college — and there's a chunk who haven't finished high school. Expecting them to not answer before they've finished their training is unrealistic.

Further, we have a Help Center page dedicated to discussing how to answer a question. The bullet I think should be at the top of the list is "answer well-asked questions," which many users ignore (if they know the rule at all). Holding querents to well-asked questions would do more for improving answers than hoping any new user will improve their answering skills. Here's that page for reference:

- [How do I write a good answer?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Besides, the whole point of the up-vote/down-vote system is to express the belief that, in the case of a question:

> (UP) This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.
> (DOWN) This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

and in the case of an answer:

> (UP) This answer is useful.
> (DOWN) This answer is not useful.

That the average user uses up-voting/down-voting to merely express popularity or appreciation is beside the point. A mechanism exists to filter poor answers. (And if they're really poor, they can be flagged for deletion).

**So, what do we do when, for example, an answer expresses an academically out-dated belief that's still popularly regarded as true?**

Unsurprisingly, this is NOT unique to the social sciences. Humanity's understanding of both themselves and the universe they live in is constantly expanding and evolving. New hypotheses replace old hypotheses and it takes time for that to percolate through the general populace.<sup>2</sup> I've had several answers over the years where people pointed out to me that my understanding was outdated.<sup>3</sup>

*But does that make my answer useless to the querent?*

And that's the fundamental problem with defining "answer quality" on a site that's dedicated to imagination and creativity. The casual insight of an "uneducated" user can quite literally be *the exact answer the OP was looking for* because we're supposed to be focused on building fictional worlds, not copies of Earth.

**@Python's right, we should allow the querent the privilege of caring about what a "quality answer" looks like.**

We have tags that theoretically set these standards.

- *No tag...*, useful answers are open to the interpretation of the respondents based on the expectations set in the query and the tags used to identify its context.
- [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic), anything goes so long as it operates within the querent's magic system.
- [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction), indicating that while science should be the basis of an answer, wide birth is allowed in its interpretation or application, even to fantastic results.
- [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based), indicating that science should be the basis of an answer, and how it's applied should represent at least a *suspension-of-disbelief* scientific application, but outright proving your point with mathematics or citations is not required (but appreciated).
- [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science), indicating the answer MUST be the basis of an answer, that it's application MUST adhere to a strict interpretation of science, and the answer MUST contain supporting mathematics and citations.

I've complained before about the science-* tags because they don't cover the gamut of querent expectations and don't entirely express what a good answer would look like.[1](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8379/40609),[2](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8363/40609),[3](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8282/40609) But there is a LOT of historical inertia behind those three tags, so they're really difficult to improve.

Nevertheless, they (combined with the Help Center page and the "Good/Bad Subjective" blog) represent the Stack's effort to achieve your goals. Although I believe improving the questions will go further toward improving answer quality than will educating users about writing good answers, I'm all for trying to do it. But...

**Here's the problems, based on experience.**

- Users almost never read tag wikis. And even when they do, they frequently don't use tags properly (the [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) tag is the worst offender and best example). Worse, because we don't even mention the magic, science-fiction, science-based, and hard-science tags in the Help Center, new users don't know they exist until they see them on other posts. It's amazing how many times new users use the [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag thinking it refers to the *literary genre.*
- If it ain't in the Help Center, it doesn't matter.
- If it is in the Help Center, it's an uphill battle to convince anyone to do it.
- No matter how thoroughly or clearly the expectations are written, there will always be someone who thinks the person asking for a better answer is misinterpreting/misapplying the expectations or violating the CoC for pointing out someone else's weaknesses.

And finally...

- I think a concise explanation of answer quality expectations that meets the needs for the wide variety of topics we allow on this Stack would be next to impossible to achieve. But that's just my opinion.

**Conclusion**

I think there are other issues more important than this one.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *And here you and I will likely always disagree. I don't consider Electronics to be a definitive science. Our understanding of it changes. There are things twenty years ago we EEs **knew from mathematics and experience could NEVER be done.** And yet EEs are doing them today. Social sciences don't even rank on the same scale of predictability — and yet you want us to treat them like they do as if today's understanding of human behavior, like today's understanding of Electronics, is somehow the end-all of knowledge and not just the current best-guess. I get it that this Stack would benefit from a better understanding of today's social and behavioral hypotheses... but I'm not willing to take them more seriously than I do my own academic background.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *A fair number of people still think oil comes from dinosaurs.... Although I'd hope the majority of said believers are over the age of 20. If not, schools must really stink.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *The majority of times this has happened to me have been questions about Einsteinian Physics and Climate. The last time I cracked a book about those subjects was 30 years ago. Back then, those **textbooks** were considered authoritative. See the problem? I had no reason to believe my answers were inadequate.*</sub>

Comment: 1) You misrepresent my previous post. I did not say that questions should be left to professionals to answer. I said that one should rely on existing science and research. One does not have to have a degree, although it helps, to do their research. And there is no one and nothing that will change my position on this. The consequences of spreading cultural myths are way too big and affect way too many people. The disaster myths, for example, show up in contingency plans and diminish their effectiveness. Myths about rape victims lead to humiliation of said victims and their cases' dismissal.

Comment: 2) I am concerned with the attitude of the answerers. For example, you say that the last time you read about a specific topic was 30 years ago. There is nothing wrong with it. It is expected. But why did not you check the current state of knowledge when you wrote your answer? Why did not you think it through?

Comment: 3) You are building a strawman by talking about experts. I specifically linked the debate about the Back It Up! policy. I do not advocate for expert-only answers. It is not possible and not desirable. Non-experts can provide unique perspectives and original solutions because they can think outside of established academic frameworks and methodologies. This is extremely valuable. However, these novel approaches, perspectives, and solutions are only viable when non-experts do their research and have a sufficient understanding of the topic. This is very different from pure speculation.

Comment: @Otkin Concerning (2). Why would I? On [physics.se] and when using the [tag:hard-science] tag that level of attention is warranted. But this is an inherently creative and subjective site. The OP's world may or may not even reflect that level of detail or care. In fact, the OP may have changed the rules of physics making such research entirely irrelevant.

Comment: 4) I expected that someone would bring the magic. Indeed, there are no experts on magic. But I would prefer to see answers that are well-thought-out and have as little self-contradiction as possible. This was one of the suggestions for the implementation of the Back It Up! policy for this kind of subject. I believe it is reasonable and achievable.

Comment: @Otkin Concerning (3). The reason I'm focusing on experts is because the expectation of answer research (which you're holding to a higher degree than the expectation of question research, which is a much bigger problem), is nonsensical for many of the questions and therefore can't be consistently demanded. Indeed, in many cases, I'm of the opinion that we're expecting a far greater dependence on established science than any answer (or question) should have. The goal on this Stack is the consistent use of world rules, not world rules that only reflect real life science.

Comment: @Otkin Concerning (4). Yes, it's reasonable. No, it's not achievable. Look at how much trouble we're having just getting people to read the [help], pay attention to the [tour], and respond when directed to advice in [meta]. Much of what you're asking for already exists in the [help]. Why do you think more will help? What's missing really isn't more rules - but more police. (If you don't agree with that, then why ask for rules?)

Comment: I do not have time right now to answer your comments, I will do it tomorrow. But please do not make assumptions on my behalf. You do not know about my expectations. Please read my words carefully. Please pay attention to the reciprocity principle.

Comment: @Otkin If I don't know about your expectations, then you failed to state them clearly in your post. I have nothing to work with other than what you've said here and in the past.

Comment: (2) There are plenty of reasons to verify your own words: Pride (as in being proud of a job well done), self-respect, respect to the questioner, intellectual integrity, ethics, desire to help, self-improvement, social responsibility, or personal responsibility. These should be enough, IMO. If you need more I can list more.

Comment: (3) By focusing on experts you are debating your own strawman, not me. You also misrepresent my position, as noted in (1). I expect you to verify your facts. I do expect you to use logic and avoid sweeping generalisations. I would also advocate for the explicit listing of as many assumptions as possible. I do not expect you to be able to talk about every topic at the level of an expert. I also expect that you respect every condition listed in the question and ask for clarifications when necessary. In addition, I expect respect to the OP and their understanding of their question.

Comment: (4) I am not asking for rules for this. Rules are useless in this case, IMO. I am talking about the attitudes and overall culture of this stack. I also don't think that more policing would do any good. You can force people to be formally polite, but you cannot force people to be kind. The same with the quality of answers: You can force people to provide links, but you cannot force them to strive for good answers. This can be achieved only by cultivating specific attitudes and values. My query is not a policy proposal, it is a study of attitudes. I must thank you for your contribution

Comment: (2) This isn't meant to be rude, but how old are you? The vast, vast majority of my background is current and valid. I have no intention of assuming that I'm wrong just because I occasionally find that I am. I have no desire to live in a world, a nation, or a community that expects anyone (much less everyone) to assume they're always wrong. That just underscores my opinion that this is a low priority issue.

Comment: (4) Ah, psychologists. What you need is to take a class in law. You're welcome if you believe you've established a meaningful baseline. Shall I flag your post as a violation of the Code of Conduct for having no purpose but to inspire discord and argument? Nah. You wouldn't learn a thing from it.

Comment: I think that this discussion is no longer productive. It seems that there is something in me that triggers you and you stop behaving civilly. I think it would be best to return to our previous situation where I do not communicate with you. Please, try to avoid repeating your previous mistakes. This time I will not be flagging your comments for deletion.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost it doesn't have to be just a library, there's google scholar for that and also almost every city out there has a public library with free books.

Worldbuilding.SE seems more like a user to user website, which means question makers are free to specify what they seek in an answer and the level of opinion vs reality they are willing to accept.

Comment: Strictly speaking, questions soliciting opinions are off-topic on the WB.SE: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask (Be on-topic section). If by 'level of opinion' you mean speculation (i.e. a theory or conjecture without firm evidence) does it make sense to you to require research for questions? Or close questions because they can lead to speculative answers?

Comment: @Otkin “Strictly speaking, questions soliciting opinions are off-topic on the WB.SE” really? Because that’s not what the rule is. Subjectivity is allowed in many circumstances.

Comment: @Topcode This is the exact rule: *Our community is defined by a specific set of topics that you can view in the help center; please stick to those topics and **avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion**.* (emphasis added)

Comment: @Otkin it’s almost like that is a broad statement with exceptions. “Some subjective questions are allowed (lists allowed subjective questions)”

Comment: @Topcode A lot of this has to do with the lack of definitions. We can say that every question asks for an opinion (and it will be true because all answers are opinions even if they are referenced). However, are all opinions the same? Is your opinion based on your years of expertise and supported by facts, evidence, and data the same as my opinion based on overhearing an influencer on Youtube? Subjective does not always mean speculative. In fact, it may very well be that your and my positions are not that different once we agree on some definitions.

Comment: @Otkin --- I agree: not all opinions are "the same"! But when it comes to irrealia -- dragons, flying humanoids, magic, kissing planets, sentient sponges and the like, no one's opinion really weighs more or less than anyone else's. This is the nature of a creative forum like this. Guesses can be right or wrong, opinions can be appropriate or inappropriate, speculation can be wild or rational. All of them can be either/or as well as both/and. I don't SE in general much cares which definition of any of those we use, simply because its model doesn't really work well with the (cont)

Comment: (cont) non-factual and is not designed or optimised to work with the counter-factual or the unreal. The further we go in that direction, the closer wild and rational speculation become until they merge into unity.

Answer (score -1):

#### Dipping My Toes in the Fuming Acid Bath

***EDIT: This response addresses only the original, unedited question***.

I do have some comments on the linked discussion about a proposed [Back It Up policy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/back-it-up-policies).

**Mourdos**: By in large I concur with this answer most strongly. WB is actually designed to handle good quality speculative and opinion based queries. (I think we've got enough consensus to say that a query like "which colour should my fairy godmother's wand star be? I like green, but I want all your opinions!" is doubleplus ungood ad extremissima ipsissima. Almost every other query in this forum, barring the *hard science* and *science based* questions are  to some extent looking for an opinion.

I have no problem with divulging sources if I think they're really and truly warranted. But on the other wing, I too **believe that insisting upon sources for speculation and imagination will not only be detrimental to this site, but would probably kill it**.

**Community Wiki**: This one is really an answer to different question, but I really do like the idea of a **Pseudoscience / Fantastic Science** tag that would compliment the hard science / science based tags. Like the science tags, the pseudoscience tags would require some research and sources; only in stead of physics and chemistry, we'd be looking for standard works on alchemy, magic, divination, homeopathy, chiropractic, theosophy and discarded science (phenomena like phlogiston or the expanding Earth theory).

Such tags could reduce the amount of wild speculation and zany opinionification that questions of magic sometimes engender.

**KRyan**: The OP's own response addresses quality fairly well, and I'd consider it the "common sense" response. You can give the zambonniest answer ever seen on WB, but so long as it ticks one of these "back it up" boxes, I'd likely consider it a quality answer.

**Styphon**: I 100% concur with the notion that encouraging respondents in general to link to their sources, we shouldn't be in the business of enforcing such a rule. With the exception of hard science / pseudoscience, which do / would require citation.

I'd say that the overall solution is to **encourage users to back up their facts *wherever absolutely necessary*, but not to enforce such a policy except in the case of tags that require citation**. This I think is the natural extension & compliment to Mourdos's answer.

#### Slathering on the Caustic Lye

Once we have some linked examples, I'd like to explore Otkin's underlying questions.

Comment: I do not think that your answer represents Back It Up! policy as it was discussed. It is not a policy that requires references (sources) and was never designed as such. KRyan's answer actually does a very good job explaining this. 'Every answer needs to justify the conclusions it comes to.' is the real core of that policy.

Comment: @Otkin -- Fair enough. However, your query isn't about the Back It Up proposal at all. You state very clearly: *Today's WB.SE has a great number of answers that are poorly researched ... etc. I wonder if this is the kind of answers today's community wants.* Clearly, you're interested in what's going on now within the context of a long running discussion that includes that proposal. My job isn't to address what you're not asking about, but rather to address your current question as it relates to Back It Up.

Comment: From my point of view, you clearly misunderstood my intent. It seems that you want to dispute my evaluation of answers rather than address my actual request. Would it help if I scrap that paragraph and state something like 'The quality of many answers is not as great as I would like them to be' or 'The information provided in many answers is not always full or correct as far as I know'?

Comment: @Otkin -- A fair response! Just don't blame me if I misunderstand your intent. It's on you as querent to be clear what your intent actually is! Thus far, I am not disputing anything you've said. In fact, I was crystal clear that I *have some comments on the linked discussion about a proposed Back It Up policy*. You didn't make that proposal or participate in the discussion; in fact, I clearly indicated what my answer so far is about:  therefore I can not have disputed anything you said. (cont)

Comment: (cont) -- When it comes to dealing with anything you have said, I was again crystal clear in saying that *once we have some linked examples, I'd like to explore Otkin's underlying questions.* I can neither dispute nor agree with your position and your query until you provide me with the context in which I should understand your position and the criteria by which you'll judge an answer. For now, all I can do is comment on the proposal you linked to. ***Finish your question***.  I'll be happy to finish my answer! (cont)

Comment: (cont) -- You can scrap whatever you like. The only thing I actually need you to do is finish your question! You're clearly asking about the shambles and ruins state of answers on Main, but you don't point to any as examples of what you're talking about. Until you do that, I can't proceed any further.

Answer (score -1):

### Tag it

**Loosen up for openers and answerers, but register: let tags indicate quality**

My proposal: peer-mods should *actively maintain* tags. When SE would ever want to adhere to your above quality proposal, they could move implausible scenario questions and/or non-backed up answers into *another* forum section, named *WB fantasy*, using the tags to filter things. Your preference will be the remaining forum, that is *WB scientific*

**SE decides, some time in the future**

You won't have to bother current  *WB unified* members with any demands. When we maintain the tags properly, SE may manage things differently and split up WB, let mods decide moves..

**Freedom**

Until SE splits things up, members on *WB unified* should be free to ask science related stuff *and also* things about fantasy weapons, implausible or hybrid creatures, flat Earths, or hairstyles for astronauts.. askers can acknowledge implausible answers, or accept answers without any references. When the asker doesn't get the references, peer mods can decide afterward, to *remove* the high quality indicators (=science tags)

1. Adding tags

It rarely happens, but anyone having 2000 points or more can add tags. You can add a tag, say science-based, when the question and answer are sound and references are put. Or when the question asks for a plausible *and* realistic scenario and it has an acknowledged answer, add a reality-check tag.

2. Removing tags

Remove a tag, when a question, or its acknowledged answer does not meet requirements of the tag: there should be proper "Back it Up", when there is a science-related tag involved, *also* in the question there should be references.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am perfectly fine with the scope of the WB.SE. I am actually opposed to the scope narrowing that happened in recent years. I mentioned that I would like to see the requirements for questions and answers to match. However, I also said that I do not expect people to agree with me.

Comment: @Otkin you say *"I mentioned that I would like to see the requirements for questions and answers to match"*  ok In my above proposal I included the acknowledged answer. It does not "cover" all answers, some of them are low quality they will go down anyway. The peer mod can remove a science tag, when the question has not been answered with sufficient references. That would at least balance question and the (one, acknowledged) answer.

Answer (score -1):

#### WtF

The query has now been edited to include a whole host of issues ranging from the OP's evaluation of my answer to the OP's psychological profile.

This response only addresses the newly added section.

> The purpose of this query is not to start a debate about my own
> position regarding the quality of answers or my evaluation of answers.
> The former is not possible as I do not have a clear position (which I
> stated before) and I am not proposing any policies or guidelines. The
> latter is something that I wanted to avoid because the discussion will
> turn to be about specific answers and their merits rather than the
> general quality of answers and whether any guidelines are needed.

Fair enough. I can't speak for others, but I didn't read your question as if you asking us to help you evaluate answers. While it's not immediately clear what you don't have a position on, it is pretty clear what your question is about. This clarification is welcome just to ward off any evil spirits.

> My intent was expressed in the last sentence of the original version:
> At this time I am trying to learn what other people think about the
> answers and whether there should be some guidelines for them. In other
> words, I wanted people to share their thoughts about answers and their
> quality and whether any guidelines are necessary.

For my part, this is what I asked you clarify. I can't reasonably talk about "what I think about the answers" unless we're looking at the same set of answers. Before fruitful discussion can begin, we need to establish common ground and review common data.

I'd still love to have this conversation with you (and others)! None of us can do this meaningfully if you refuse to show us some answers that you'd like to discuss!

> Since @elemtilas insists on providing specific examples of what I
> would consider a low-quality answer and explicitly states that they
> would want to hear my opinion about their own answer, I will use their
> answer to this query (as of 4 February 2022, 18:20 GMT) as such an
> example.

Specifically, I asked about any answers I've written that fall under what you categorise as *poorly researched, based on speculation, unverified assumptions, personal preferences, 'common sense', ideologies, tropes* and the like. My answer was based on reading your original query, asking for clarification, reading all the answers to your question, reading the linked question and answers and all the associated comments. That's research. My answer begins with commentary on the linked discussion; it is not yet complete, as I await further clarification from the OP. I didn't make any assumptions, but when I do, I verify all of them. Preferences, common sense, ideologies and tropes didn't figure in to the answer I'm writing, and I honestly don't see that they will, though they might! If they do, I will note such as is customary.

I should, however, have been even clearer! I read the question as referring to quality of answers on Main, not here in Meta. I've written 455 responses on Main. Perhaps you could evaluate a few of those?

Especially within the context of my other Meta answer being a WIP contingent on you clarifying your query!

> There are 2 big problems with this answer:
>
> it is a response to the linked Back It Up! policy discussion, not this
> query (and @elemtilas does acknowledge this)
>
> It is worth noting that @elemtilas justifies this approach by saying
> that my query is unfinished and not clear enough to them. They even
> threatened to VTC it.

I do not "justify" anything. I was clear in stating that my initial comments were in regard to the "discussion about" the proposed policy, not about the policy itself. I offered these preliminary comments on the linked policy discussion as that post and its answers are pertinent to the OP's present query.  I continue to be more than happy to address OP's main query when it's eventually clarified!

> It should be mentioned that @elemtilas is the author of Is it Fair to
> Encourage People to NOT Answer Questions that Need to be Closed?,
> where they advocate for not answering questions that they find to be
> unsatisfactory. Therefore, their own response is not only inconsistent
> with the WB.SE guidelines for answers but also with their own position
> regarding answering questions.

The OP's question does not need to be closed. It is not unsatisfactory. There is no need assume malice.

> in their response @elemtilas does not represent the original Back It
> Up! policy or discussion about it accurately (and they agree with this
> evaluation)

I do not claim to represent anything. The Back It Up! policy was introduced by the OP in the context of a query about the state of present time answers. It is thus a valid topic for discussion within the context of any answer to the OP's query.

> The way @elemtilas builds their argument and formats their post
> distorts the original meaning of the Back It Up! policy and may lead
> readers to believe that it was an attempt to require references for
> every single answer. It was never the case. The core of the policy
> was: Every answer needs to justify the conclusions it comes to.

I did not "build an argument" for anything. I structured my response to separate one section of comments on the responses to the linked policy from a WIP section on the question at hand. I have no comment on the original policy at all. If I did, I would either respond to it directly or else draw up a revised proposal of my own. I have no reason to do either.

> I see this kind of answer not only as poor-quality but detrimental to
> the WB.SE. It sets a precedent for being off-topic. It also misleads
> the readers. In addition, it makes it impossible for me to trust the
> author's words even when it comes to their expressed attitudes and
> positions on issues because their acts are not consistent with their
> words.

It is poor quality only in so far is it remains incomplete. It remains incomplete until the question is finally clarified. Once the question is clarified, I guarantee you'll get a stellar answer that not only addresses the linked policy discussion, but also addresses any issue you have with the state of more recent answers in the forum!

The linked policy and its responses are central to the present question. Just FYI: you have also brought your own inner psychological issues into the question, among which appear to be trust issues, belligerence, history of accusative behaviour, passive aggression and so forth. Otkin, do you really want to go down this road? I strongly urge you to purge your question of any of your personal issues.

> I will not provide any additional specific examples of low-quality
> answers as I do not believe that it would be very constructive to this
> discussion. However, since @elemtilas has difficulty understanding my
> point about disaster myths I will add a note on this.

Fair enough. You've just determined that your own question is now pretty much unanswerable. I think it could be argued that this is a valid Vote to Close rationale.

> Every answer that features mass panic or social chaos as inevitable
> and 'natural' (as in 'it's human nature') outcomes in disaster
> scenarios is an answer that lacks research because both of these
> notions are among debunked disaster myths. There is even a Wikipedia
> article about this. Moreover, these answers are, if I put it kindly,
> irresponsible since the propagation of disaster myths worsens the
> outcomes for real people affected by real disasters.

I can only take your word for this. I honestly don't know how answers that involve mass panic or social chaos fit in with the linked policy, and since you're still not "backing up" your assertion with any kind of data, I'm just going to have to leave it at that.

Comment: And this is precisely why I was so opposed to linking specific answers. This is not a discussion that I wanted to have.

Comment: @Otkin -- If you didn't want to have the above discussion, then perhaps you might want to reconsider your approach in future? I've said it a few times already, and I'd still encourage you to salve the question so we can get on with the real discussion. Completely up to you what the next steps are!

Comment: I complied with all your requests. However, you still did not attempt to address any of my interests in any constructive way. It seems that we want to discuss different things. Perhaps you could start your own discussion and ask about things that you want to talk about? If I find it interesting I will participate. But I see no need for us to engage in any further conversation here.

Comment: @Otkin -- Fair enough. I guess take your toys and go home -- if that's what you want, then I can't stop you!

Comment: Dear @elemtilas, I offered you to play with my toys. But you instead decided to hit my head again and again while complaining that my toys are not good enough for you. I kindly request you to go play elsewhere. This is my final word on this matter. I will not respond to any more off-topic comments.